# paypal create subscription nodejs rest api request failed with status code 400

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

Hello all paypal developers, I ran into a problem when creating a subscription via this endpoint `/v1/billing/subscriptions` which I implement from the Paypal rest SDK document tutorial. I got a 400 bad request I am not sure what is the exact problem?

source link:
https://developer.paypal.com/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create

does Paypal company has modified the endpoint or do they move to the new one? please tell me as well.

Comment: Show the complete request JSON you are transmitting, the complete JSON response received, and the headers of you request.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved :** Remove `start_time` from the body. also if you want to put `return_url` using `http://127.0.0.1/` instead of `localhost`.